# Android appcompat lib + design lib = build error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

After add this library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I can't build the app because I have this error:

```
/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values/values.xml
    Error:(2) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined
```

Is possible to use togheter this libs?

Thanks!
Luis

p.s. I need (for now) the design lib for the FloatingActionButton (fab).

Comment: Does it compile if use __22.2.1__ version for design library (and all other support libraries) too?

Comment: You have different versions of various android-support libraries, why? I bet this breaks the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the attribute rippleColor is being used more than once (Dependencies and your own application).

Check your xmls for an attribute with the name "rippleColor" and see if it is being used multiple times. Rename it to something else if it is.

Remove this line if you have an attr file in the project:

```
<attr name="rippleColor" format="color" />
```

Comment: You're right! I thought the error was a color named " rippleColor " and instead was a attrs. Thank you!